# Custom Component similar to autocomplete in JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a specific requirement where I need a list in a text field which should display  equivalent word/s for the entered word. This sounds similar to auto complete, but the difference is , if user types Colour , the suggestion should display Color, the moment he completed typing Colour, and also vice versa.  This will never happen in an autocomplete.In auto complete the suggestion will display only as long as the words have common letters. I was following this link.
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

But this does not meet the above requirement. Later I tried to create a custom list which will get populated , once the user completes the word. But still the list is not getting displayed unless I delete the last 3 character (in the above scenario) and come back to the place where the letter are common to both the words.

Kindly suggest. Any help appreciated.

Comment: So you are looking for some [Levenstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `autocomplete`'s option of a function source.  Then you can determine for any given term, what matches to return.  In the below example, I've defined two substitution lists - teh/the, and color/colour.  If the user types `col` they will receive both as a suggestion.  Once they type `color` it suggests `colour`.  Similar for `teh` and `the`.

If you don't want it to return until it's a full match, get rid of the `lastIndexOf` logic (which is really a `startsWith` equivalent.

```js
$( function() {
    
    var availableTags = [
     ["color", "colour"],
      ["the", "teh"]
    
    ];

    var tagFunction = function(request, response) {
      var term = request.term.toLowerCase();
     for (var i = 0; i < availableTags.length; i++)
      {      
        if (availableTags[i][0].lastIndexOf(term, 0) === 0 
            && availableTags[i][1].lastIndexOf(term, 0) === 0)
        {
          response(availableTags[i]);
        }
       else if (availableTags[i][0].lastIndexOf(term, 0) === 0)
        {
         response([availableTags[i][1]]);
        }
        else if (availableTags[i][1].lastIndexOf(term, 0) === 0)
        {
          response([availableTags[i][0]]);
        }
      }
    }
    
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: tagFunction
    });
  } );
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
 
<input id="tags" />
```